# Run Capybara-firebug without Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

Is there a way to run capybara-firebug without Cucumber?

I would like to use it with rspec integration tests only and the Before '@firebug' and the Then definition do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can switch current driver by yourself:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_with_firebug
```

Comment: The problem is that the @firebug is not parsed and the Then stop and let me debug is not created. Another weird thing emerged when I looked at the code and then wanted to just use require 'rails/debug' with debugger -basically what the Then stop...' does - and nothing happened. rspec apparently does not react to my debugger call even when called with the -d flag - I will have to investigate that further.